Do private members/methods inherently violate the open-closed principle?
Doesnt private members and methods inherently violate the open-closed principle?
Given that private, protected and public modifiers are supported.
I came across this many times in codebases where developers use private modifiers for members and methods for whatever reason which in turn requires me to copy entire blocks of code to be able to extend it.
I feel like many people just use private out of habit because its use cases are very nieche in my opinion and almost all the time protected does the job as well.

BTW. Apple removed “protected” from Swift. And Chris Lattner knows a thing or two about software development.

If you insist on linking your problem to the OCP I would say private nembers enforce it rather than violate it: you are supposed to extend/inherit, not mess with the base class.

private lets you do the closed bit

Sounds to me like the private modifier is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

@MartinMaat But I cant call any private methods of the base class...

I think you've discovered out why that style of inheritance has fallen out of favor.

@CodeSpirit private signals it is an implementation detail that is not to be exposed in the object's interface. If you feel, as a user of the object, you need access to a private member, you either do not understand the use case of the object or the object is just not suitable for your use case. If you want to drive in a nail and you get a screw driver, you don't try and modify the screw driver to serve your purpose, you get (or make) a hammer.

Protected is an invitation to infringe the lesser known history rule of LSP.

@MartinMaat Yes I know but I often see that people just use private methods to group code. My point is that by limiting visibility with private you basically predict that noone will want to use this which in turn may cause people to copy or reimplement the same code in the future because they still want to use it. I have to add that most of the time I work with scripting languages so its common to view the source, maybe this may not apply to compiled languages.

Thought experiment: imagine a component designed to be OCP-compliant, with certain extension points and public members, so it can be reused in a black-box fashion in several use cases. Imagine also the component has some or several private members.
Now, imagine the private members were all made public - then the same component would still be as reusable as before. So this makes it clear private members - at least technically - don't contribute to the OCP.
That still does not mean they violate the OCP. Nevertheless you are right - in real-world components, sometimes developers miss occasions for opening a possible extension point to the client by keeping something private, which should be made public. Usually, this involves more than just exchanging the keyword private by public, but sometimes this is all what appears to be needed.
However, one should not jump to the conclusion that it is better to make every member public in a reusable component "just in case". The OCP is usually only one of many goals you have to aim for when designing reusable components. Other typical goals are

to keep the component maintainable and evolvable,

to keep the number of breaking changes low when creating a new version

to keep the API of a component as simple as possible, so another dev has only to learn and understand the 5 public methods to use it and can ignore the 95 private methods which they don't care for.


And that's why private members are required - to keep the the impact of changes low, and the whole component comprehensible for a client. That's especially important when you don't know all the clients who are potentially reusing your component - by making a method or field private, you signal to them

you don't have to know what this method does when you just want to use this component

this part of the code might become subject to change at a later point in time

don't fiddle around with this member from the outside, you may accidentally break some invariant.


Hence, the design of reusable, long-living components is often a trade-off. If one

is 100% sure a component's source code will never-ever become subject to change, not even for a bug fix, and

does not care whether a component is used by clients in an anticipated "correct" way, or if clients may shoot themselves in the foot


then one may use only public members. But as soon as you want to provide updates and new releases, you have to find a balance between private and public members.

For inheritance to work well you need to design your base class with inheritance in mind. In that case you should carefully consider what properties and methods should be protected or private, as well as 'virtual' or 'abstract'.
But this is quite a bit of work, so most classes are just not designed for inheritance, and just make everything private. Ideally these should be marked as non-inheritable, but this is unfortunately often not done. Trying to inherit from a class that is not designed for it is likely a poor idea.
I would also recommend avoiding dogmatism, "open/closed principle" is a good idea, but it is possible to get carried away. Just like with all other design patterns you need to know what problem it addresses and where it is applicable.
If you are making an public API it is a very good idea to seriously think about what things users will want to extend, how, and many other design considerations. There is also a trend of Composition over inheritance, so you might want to consider other methods of extending behavior than inheritance.
If you are developing an internal class then you should have a good understanding of how the class is used. So modifications should have a lower cost.

Private methods does not in themselves violate the open-closed principle, but a class with only private methods would violate the principle because such a class is not extensible.
Your problem with having to copy-paste code points to a more fundamental problem with the open-closed principle, and the reason the principle have largely been abandoned for real-world development. (The principle mostly only exist in academia and teaching at this point).
The fundamental problem is: It is not possible to design a class to be extensible for any purpose. Extensibility have to be deliberately designed. The open-closed principle can only really be followed if the the general purpose of the extension was already predicted when the class was designed.

"the reason the principle have largely been abandoned for real-world development. (The principle mostly only exist in academia and teaching at this point)" - what a huge misconception. The pricinple is used in real-world development wherever reusable libraries and frameworks exist.

@DocBrown Many libraries and frameworks use semantic versioning (which is a controlled way to introduce changes in published libraries) because they realize keeping modules closed is neither practical nor desirable. (To be clear, I'm referring to the original definition of the open-closed principle by Bertrand Meyer.)

"It is not possible to design a class to be extensible for any purpose. Extensibility have to be deliberately designed" - 100% ack.  The open-closed principle can only really be followed if the the general purpose of the extension was already predicted when the class was designed. - I think this is not accurate  Replace "OCP" by "keeping the module closed" in that former sentence, and I will agree. And I don't think Meyer wrote something different, I scanned the related pages.

@DocBrown I'm not sure what distinction you are making there? The open-closed principle wouldn't be the open-closed principle if you remove the "closed" part.

Jacques, I disagree that one follows (or does nott follow) the OCP after a class was designed (and AFAIK neither Meyers nor Martin wrote something like that). Not the client who uses a class or component is the protagonist of the OCP, but the designer of the class, before the class is "closed" and handed over to a client. The client may or may not be able to reuse a component in a black-box fashion when the designer missed to provide the necessary extension points, but that is not "breaking the OCP" - the role "client" is technically not able to break the OCP,

@DocBrown According to Meyer the public interface of a class should not change after a class has been published. That is what the "closed" part of the principle means. So that would obviously apply to anyone - nobody is allowed to make changes to the class after this point.

I read the related section in Meyer's book again, and I have no idea where you get to the nonsensical conclusion it would be a "rule" for users of a class, not just a design principle and decomposition technique. Maybe if Meyers had found out that his writings could be interpreted in such an absurd way, he had written a clarification like Bob Martin, we can only speculate. Or we start thinking by ourselfes about the OCP what interpretation makes most sense. ...

... As you have written by yourself, you believe the OCP "only exist in academia and teaching" - so you agree that according to your understanding, the OCP isn't something which really works. But I think the real problem here is not the OCP, but your (mis)understanding of it.

@DocBrown I'm basing my understanding on Bertrand Meyers Object-Oriented Software Construction 2nd edition, where he explains that if you modify a published module, "any change or extension can trigger a painful chain reaction of changes in many other modules, which relied on the original module directly or indirectly" - obviously this is a concern after the module have been designed and published. Meyers solution to the above problem is to add new sub-classes instead of modifying the original class.

In my understanding, that sentence describes potential conquences for client when the designer of a module did not follow the OCP beforehand, but I don't see why one should think this would be part of the definition of the OCP. But as I said, instead of following some nonsensical dogmatic interpretation, why not trust yourself more? You have clearly understood, that an OCP interpretation  as a "change management process for the client" would not make much sense in reality - is it really so hard to accept that this is not what Meyers meant?

Principles like this tend go though a "game of telephone" when they are passed on from indirect sources. But if you go back to Meyers text it is actually completely straightforward to understand and not nonsensical at all. It is a question of how to adapt components to changing requirement. He says: Don't alter a class after it is published, since this might cause cascading changes. Don't create a modified copy ether, since duplicate code cause maintenance issues. Instead adapt to changing requirements by creating sub-classes which override the specific behavior you want to change.

@DocBrown OK I think I see where out disagreements come from. I just read Robert Martins take on the principle, and he does indeed give it a different spin as something which is solely applied in the design stage - we should design components such that they can be extended and doesn't have to be modified - but he doesn't say we shouldn't actually modify classes, just that is shouldn't be necessary if they are well designed. So I guess this is the interpretation you are referring to? I did attempt to make it clear I was talking about Bertrand Meyers original description of the principle.

When I make a method private, it means “it’s not designed to be reusable. If you want to reuse it, do it at your own risk and don’t come crying to me if it doesn’t work”.
Open/closed principle doesn’t come for free. Someone has to do serious work to implement it. The original developer said “I’m not paid to do it. And as far as I know, you ain’t gonna need it aka the YAGNI principle.
Now you needed the open/closed principle. And instead of implementing it, as you should have done, you did a copy/paste job, which is one of the worst mortal sins you could have committed. So you have nothing to complain about. Implementing the open/closed principle was your job and you refused to do it.

No it was not my job because im working with frameworks and libraries. My point is that if you use private methods you prohibit the usage in any child class and therefor limit the ability to extend it because you might wanna call it. Therefore theres no other solution than to copy it because you need that exact behavior in the child class. For example when extending a public method which calls a private method.

@CodeSpirit the only reason you even know about the existence of the private method is cause you decompiled or had access to the code. If that wasn't the case, you wouldn't have the problem now. The private method may change or be deleted in the future, you shouldn't relay on its existence.

Code spirit. I bet your job is primarily to create code that works and not leave a maintenance nightmare behind. And that’s exactly what you did.

And as I said, “private” doesn’t limit your ability to use it, it’s a warning sign. Here be dragons. Enter at your own risk. Like a fence around a building that will be demolished with dynamite in an hour. To you, the fence limits your ability to enter the building.

The argument for private fields is that by changing their values in a derived class you modify the functionality of the original class.
eg.
class Reactor
{
   public int temp;
   public void AdjustCoolingRods()
   {
     if(temp > 100) { raiseRods() }
     else { lowerRods() }
   }
}

class MyReactor : Reactor
{
   public void PlayWelcomeMessageOnBoot()
   {
      temp = 0;
   }
}

Clearly by making temp private we protect the AdjustCoolingRods function against modified behaviour
So its the "Closed" part of the Open Closed principle which the private access modifier is complying with.
I'm basing this largely off OCP: The Open-Closed Principle : Robert Martin

Make all Member Variables Private. This is one of the most commonly
held of all the conventions of OOD. Member variables of classes should
be known only to the methods of the class that defines them. Member
variables should never be known to any other class, including derived
classes. Thus they should be declared private, rather than public or
protected. In light of the open-closed principle, the reason for this
convention ought to be clear. When the member variables of a class
change, every function that depends upon those variables must be
changed. Thus, no function that depends upon a variable can be closed
with respect to that variable.


I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding here. "Closed for modification" means "you don't have to change the source code", not "Closed against modifying a behaviour through some public member".

hmm i think you are wrong on that. let me find the source

there added quote and link

Yes, that linked PDF explains it well, see page 2: "They are “Closed for Modification”. The source code of such a module is inviolate. No one is allowed to make source code changes to it.. Bob Martin speaks about changing the source code of members, not the values which are assigned to them.

I mean, that's the one liner description at the top, but the rest of the paper goes into the details, I've adapted the example to make it more clear, but its there starting page 9 Heuristics and Conventions. "OCP is the root motivation behind... Make all member vars private"

"consider what happens if even one client takes advantage of the writable nature of status, and changes its value. Suddenly, this one client could affect every other client of Device."

If I can’t change the behaviour, why would I have modified instances at all? If the behaviour is the same, then I just use the original.

? im not sure if that question is for me. the OCP says dont modify, extend
